# Elegant and high performance alternative to bind()

Tags: javascript, performance

I currently stumbled on an issue with bind where I believe it is degrading my performance. Calling bind on every recursion seems pretty bad.

Im currently looking for an elegant and high performance way of dealing with such situations:

What would be ideal in this case?

```
class AlotMonster {
    constructor() {
        this.names = ['a lot', 'alot'];
        this.method();
      }

    method() {
        let choice = Math.round(Math.random());
        let currentName = this.names[choice];

        console.log(currentName);

        requestAnimationFrame(this.method.bind(this));
      }
}

new AlotMonster();
```

Comment: just call it once in the constructor `this.boundMethod = this.method.bind(this);` and use `this.boundMethod` in the subsequent calls.

Comment: @georg seriously? Didnt think about it

Comment: @georg can this ever be an issue performancewise? binding I mean

Comment: no idea... try it and let us know.

Comment: Why do you think `bind` was not performant?

Comment: The performance killer will be `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `bind`

Answer (score 1):

You could instead just use an arrow function, which has lexical `this` binding. It doesn't look like you're making use of the prototypal nature of your method and want it to be bount to a specific instance anyway:

```
class AlotMonster {
    constructor() {
        this.names = ['a lot', 'alot'];

        this.method = () => {
            let choice = Math.round(Math.random());
            let currentName = this.names[choice];

            console.log(currentName);

            requestAnimationFrame(this.method);
        };  

        this.method();
    }
}

new AlotMonster();
```